Issue with Roboflow API in iOS Swift – Bounding Box Detected, But No Text Extracted
I'm currently working on an iOS app for my senior project using Swift, and I’m integrating the Roboflow API to detect and extract grocery items from receipt images. The API correctly returns bounding box predictions, but I’m facing issues with extracting text from these bounding boxes.
The problem:
I send the receipt image (Base64 encoded) to the Roboflow API and receive the bounding box predictions in response.
While the API provides bounding box coordinates (for items like Date, Item, Subtotal, etc.), no text is being extracted from those bounding boxes.
I suspect the issue might be related to the way I handle the API response or the timing of the OCR extraction.
Here’s the relevant portion of my Swift code:
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://detect.roboflow.com/YOUR-MODEL/1?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY")! as URL)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let postData = NSMutableData(data: "base64=\(encodedImageString)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
request.httpBody = postData as Data

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
    guard error == nil else {
        print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
        return
    }

    guard let data = data else {
        print("No data received.")
        return
    }

    do {
        // Attempt to decode the response from Roboflow API
        if let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any],
           let predictions = jsonResponse["predictions"] as? [[String: Any]] {
           
            // Loop through the predictions and print bounding boxes
            for prediction in predictions {
                if let classType = prediction["class"] as? String, 
                   let x = prediction["x"] as? Double, 
                   let y = prediction["y"] as? Double, 
                   let width = prediction["width"] as? Double, 
                   let height = prediction["height"] as? Double {
                    
                    print("Bounding box: Class: \(classType), x: \(x), y: \(y), width: \(width), height: \(height)")
                    
                    // Attempt to extract text within the bounding boxes (This part is where the issue might be)
                } else {
                    print("No bounding box found in prediction.")
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Invalid response from API.")
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("Failed to decode JSON: \(error)")
    }
}

task.resume()

Question:
Is there a specific way I should be handling OCR extraction within bounding boxes?
Could there be a timing issue that is causing this? If so, how do I ensure the OCR process completes before proceeding?
Any guidance on what might be causing this issue or how to improve my approach would be greatly appreciated!
Additional Info:
I'm using Swift for iOS development.
The Roboflow model I’m using has classes like Date, Item, Subtotal, etc.
What I’ve tried:

Ensuring the OCR extraction is triggered after receiving the bounding boxes.
Verifying that the bounding boxes are correct, but still, no text is being extracted from those boxes.


Hi! I wonder if OCR actually detected any text. You can try Workflows - in Roboflow platform you can create workflow with OCR block - there are a few options you can chose from. And then you can call that workflow through API call.
